# Filter huge NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm filtering an NSArray with a NSPredicate and using the filtered array for my UITableView.
I'm using this filtering when the user inputs text in a UITextField. So every time the text in the UITextField changes I'm calling my filter function.

It looks like this:

```
NSArray *hugeArray = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", input];
_resultArray = [hugeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
[_myTableView reloadData];
```

When I'm using a NSArray with a lot of objects the input becomes very slow (the complete input in the UI becomes slow).
Is there any possibility to get a better performance or run the filtered command in background?

Writing something in the UITextField shouldn't be blocked. When the UITableView will be refreshed after a very short time after the input it may be ok.

Comment: I would suggest you to use NSOperationqueue to handle the filter. If the user insert another string while filtering, then abort the old one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSPredicate` focuses on flexibility rather than speed. For an in-memory `NSArray` (i.e. not a Core Data relationship), you can generally get much better performance by just using a loop.

If it is still too slow, then there are several approaches:

- Coalesce your requests. See [Is there a simple way (in Cocoa/iOS) to queue a method call to run once in the next run loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518213/is-there-a-simple-way-in-cocoa-ios-to-queue-a-method-call-to-run-once-in-the-n) You can create a coalescing trampoline so that you only will update your list every few hundred milliseconds. That way if the user types very quickly, you don't re-filter the list every single chaacter.
- Be smarter about filtering. If you just filtered for "bo" and you now want to filter for "bob", you know it's a subset of that previous list. You don't have to re-filter everything. Writing a good algorithm for this takes a little work but can dramatically improve performance.
- Perform your filtering on an `NSOperationQueue` (easier to cancel than GCD, but GCD also works), and let the UI use KVO to notice when the filtered array changes.
- Keep track of the actual changes (adds/deletes) while filtering. You shouldn't call `reloadData` on your table view if you can help it. You should perform inserts and deletes (`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`). That avoids constantly churning your cells, and it also generally looks better. Again, the code is more complicated, but the improvements can be dramatic.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will try them out.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use a predicate and if the object order is not important (meaning the index of an object does not matter) you can convert your `NSArray` to `NSSet`. **Filtering a set (using `NSPredicate`) is much faster than an array**.

```
NSSet *hugeSet = [NSSet setWithArray:hugeArray]
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", input];
NSSet *filteredSet = [hugeSet filteredSetUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

More info on NSSet vs NSArray vs NSDictionary in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think running it in the background is the solution. Do the query on another queue, then reload the table on the main queue. With GCD it would look like this...

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", input];
        _resultArray = [hugeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [_myTableView reloadData];
          });
    });
```

Comment: This need to be done carefully. If this is done on every keystroke there will be huge problems as-is. Each new keystroke should kick off the background search but only after stopping the current background search. No sense in finishing a current search if the user updates the text and starts a new search.

Comment: You should filter into a temporary array and assign the new value of `_resultArray` on the main thread, because the table view might access its data source while the background thread is still running.

Comment: @rmaddy, true if this is a really long operation. I am not aware of a way to stop the filtering, are you?

Comment: @MartinR using an atomic property would solve this too wouldn't it? e.g. self.resultArray =

Comment: @combinatorial I wouldn't use a predicate for this. A simple `for` loop that can be quickly exited would be better. Instead of GCD I would use an `NSOperationQueue`. This way it is each to cancel each operation as needed before adding a new one.

Comment: @maddy I prefer NSPredicate instead of a `for` loop. NSPredicate has a much better syntax. In my app I have to search for different keys like `ID MATCHES[cd] theID OR name LIKE[cd] input OR user MATCHES[cd regex]` or something like this. I'm not sure, but I thought a normal loop/iteration wouldn't be faster.